# Netbeans autocomplete stopped working?

Tags: netbeans, ide, autocomplete

I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1, everything was just fine however suddenly, it has stopped detecting any changes made to the code, e.g new variables, functions, etc. If I try to refactor/rename a variable, e.g by pressing CTRL + R, it says 'Refactoring not available in this context'.

Its in a PHP project if that matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get this to work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently deleting the contents of .netbeans/var/cache/index in your user directory (application data on windows etc) fixed it.

Comment: I encountered a problem w/NB not importing JS Classes from external files in a project.  Deleting the cache (move to a different dir as a backup) fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: For windows: 
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\NetBeans\Cache`

Comment: I ran into this issue in a maven java project. I'm using NetBeans 11.3. Clearing everything in %LOCALAPPDATA%\NetBeans\Cashe\11.3\ fixed my issues. My issues began after trying to switch Java and Netbeans to UTF-16 encoding. Everything is working on UTF-8 now.

Comment: For macOS: `/Users/{username}/Library/Caches/NetBeans`. Confirmed to be working on NB 16.

Answer (score 11):

Since NetBeans 7.2 the cachedir has been moved to the following locations:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.2\` on Windows
`/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/NetBeans/7.2/` on Mac OS X
`/home/<username>/.cache/netbeans/7.2` on Unix-like systems

Source: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

Answer (score 3):

Another Solution to the problem is just start a new project and once you've started a new project. also note if you have a syntax error whilst typing it may not work. But try and see if it helps.

Comment: Netbeans really should sort this annoying bug out in newer releases.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I deleted the old project (but not contents on disk!) and started a fresh one from existing sources.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `nbproject` folder from project directory and then create a new project is works for me:

Steps:

1. Close project
2. Open project directory in windows explorer
3. Delete `nbproject`folder
4. Go to netbeans, open file menu and select "New Project"
5. Create project with existing source

:)

Comment: This worked for me, except that I didn't had to open the project again as a new project. It worked right after removing nbproject folder, when I opened Netbeans again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

tools>plugins>installed

then find the Java SE,
right click and Activate [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjtxl.png)

this works for me on netbeans 12.2

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Finally works after adding the path of the project in Tools > Options > PHP > Global Include Path > Add Folder...
and restarting

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Netbeans 11.2, autocompletion could stop working if you set JDK 8 as default for running netbeans (netbeans_jdkhome in netbeans.conf) instead of newer JDK 13.

Comment: I just installed 11.2 with JDK 13 (after having used ver 7.3 for many years on previous laptop). I use for PHP development exclusively. Auto completion NOT working for me. Tried all the solutions above. Anyone else having this issue? Should I try version 10 instead maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the background scanning of project(s) could not finish, because there were so many files in some folders. Hence autocomplete was not working.

Consider ignoring folders you dont need ("Project properties" -> "Ignored folders") and opening just one project at a time.