# Alt+Shift+O does not list all files in netbeans.

Tags: netbeans-8

**Alt+Shift+O** does not list all files in netbeans IDE. 
I have deleted all projects and then recreate project. and 
reset windows but listed only few files in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

my issue is fixed by

```
**Step 1** -> clearing cache 
For windows: **%LOCALAPPDATA%\NetBeans\Cache**
**Step 2** Then restart netbeans
**Step 3** Create new Project

Reference link click here
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928301/netbeans-autocomplete-stopped-working